# Pattern matching in grep unix command

Tags: unix, grep, command, pattern-matching

I have many lines of input with terms of the form e.g

```
(d^2*q+d^3*s*r)*Den (2*d*r + d*s + q*d)
d*Den (q - 3*d*s + 3*s - q*d)
(r*q+ q^2*d)*Den (3*d*s + q*d)
Den (d*r - d*s)
```

but also of the form

```
 (d^2*q+d^3*s*r)*Den (q-s)
Den (q+s-2*r)
```

etc,

i.e. some `Den`'s have a linear dependence on `d` (within the parantheses next to a `Den`) and some not. How to modify the pattern in `grep` from `grep -n Den file.inc` to one that once executed shows only those instances in `file.inc` where a `Den` has a `d` dependence (rather than just a `Den`)? So, instead of the 6 lines above, it would only show the first four, where there is an explicit `d` in the parantheses next to a `Den`.

Comment: `grep d file` ?

Comment: @James Brown Oh sorry I should have pointed out I have d to arbitrary power in the numerators too. I just want to single out the `Den`'s including a `d`.

Comment: You should definitely add expected output for a proper given sample to your question.

Comment: @JamesBrown Edited, thanks.

Comment: I don't know which of your 6 example input lines should show up after the matching. My best guess now is `grep -E "(Den.*d|d.*Den)" inputfile`

Comment: @WalterA Sorry for not being clear, I would like the first block of Den's in my question to show up and not the Den's in the second block, i.e only those containing a d in the Den should show up.

Comment: `(d^2*q+d^3*s*r)*Den (q-s)` starts with a `d`, so I would guess it shows up with Den. Do you mean the `d` should appear in the factor in the parentheses net to Den?
Please edit your question so people ill understand without reading the comments.

Comment: @WalterA Ok have done so, thanks.